# Loop until button is available Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, bots

I'm coding my first "bot" with python and webdriver

I would like to loop until a specific button shows up on the website. My idea is to check if the button is available. If not, sleep for a minute, reload, and check again. But I dont know the right syntax as this element seems too complicated for me.

Does anyone have a tip? [image]

Edit: When the product is sold out, this button does not exist on the product page. I guess enabled/disabled won't work here, because the button does not exist if the product is unavailable. I guess I need to check, if the button exists.

Comment: You can use try and catch block . Check the presence of webelement and if exceptions  occur catch it and continue  with loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) in python selenium to wait till the element is loaded. Or you can use javascript to check if the element exists in the DOM or not:

```
    buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("mu-button mu-button--type_alternative add-to-cart");
    if (buttons.length == 0) {
        # it doesn't exist
    } else
    {
        # do something
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Full documentation: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
```